# UIImageView. Zoom and Center to arbitrary rectangle. Can't determine correct center on screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

There is simple iPad application. Views hierarchy is:
Window - UIView - UIImageView
UIImageView has loaded image which is bigger then screen size (i.e. 1280 x 2000 against 768 x 1004). I need to zoom in arbitrary rectangular part of image (fit it on the screen) and then center it on the screen. At the moment I do zooming in following way:

```
-(IBAction)posIt:(id)sender
{
    // rectangle size and origin in image's coordinates. Its received from out of application
    CGFloat x = 550.f;
    CGFloat y = 1006.f;
    CGFloat w = 719.f;
    CGFloat h = 850.f;

    CGSize frameSize = CGSizeMake(_imgView.image.size.width, _imgView.image.size.height);
    _imgView.frame = CGRectMakeWithParts(CGPointMake(0, 0), frameSize);

    // Calculate center manually because orientation changing
    CGPoint superCenter = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2);

    // delta is the factor between size of image size and device screen
    CGFloat delta = 768.f/w;

    // resizing UIImageView to fit rectangle on the screen
    frameSize = CGSizeMake(_imgView.image.size.width * delta, _imgView.image.size.height * delta);
    _imgView.frame = CGRectMakeWithParts(CGPointMake(0, 0), frameSize);

    // Here is I'm trying to calculate center of rectangle
    _imgView.center = CGPointMake(superCenter.x + (superCenter.x - (w/2)*delta - x * delta), superCenter.y + (superCenter.y - (h/2)*delta - y * delta));
}
```

UIImageView's ContentMode parameter is AspectFit. I believe that to move one point (UIImageView's center) to another one (in order to move rectangle to the center of the superView) I shall use following formula:

*newX = oldX + oldX - rectCenterX;*

*newY = oldY + oldY - rectCenterY;*

Since UIImageView is scaled with *delta* factor, *rectCenterX* and *rectCenterY* should be multiplied with same *delta*. But I'm wrong. Rectangles centers jump out from superView center.

Is there exists some way to make these calculations correctly? What do I miss?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed correct and stable image centering. Instead of calculating center of image I'm calculating UIImageView's frame's origin coordinates like this:

```
CGPoint newOrigin = CGPointMake((-zoomRect.origin.x * delta) + superCenter.x - (zoomRect.size.width / 2) * delta, 
                                (-zoomRect.origin.y * delta) + superCenter.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2) * delta);
```

It turns out there is some difference between calculating center and origin. Anyway problem is solved. Thanks everybody.